Topological sort with added flexible constraints
I need an algorithm to manage a system that allows two types of definitions:

Variable Definitions: A variable can be defined in terms of other variables, such as a := f(x, y).
Expression Replacements: Functions or expressions can be replaced by other expressions, for instance, f(a, b) := g(x, y). I will call f(a, b) the antecedent and g(x, y) the replacement.

During evaluation, both definitions are applied. I need to perform a check to eliminate the possibility of

Circular Definitions: Situations where variables reference each other directly or indirectly, such as a := f(b) and b := g(a).
Infinite Replacement Loops: Scenarios where replacement rules trigger each other in a cycle, such as f(a, b) := g(x, y) and g(x, y) := h(f(a, b)).

The lack of circular definitions can be checked using a topological sort. For expression replacements, the only way I can think of is by asserting that the replacement reduces some positive invariant of the expression with respect to the antecedent. The only invariant I can think of is the maximum index of a variable in the topological sort, that is, if E is an expression with variables {a, b, c}, the maximum of the indexes of {a, b, c} in the sort. Is this approach correct? Is there another, more sensible way? Is there any moderately easy to understand literature on this?
To check this, I would have to deal with 2 types of constrain in the sort

Normal dependencies (nd): Variable A is defined using variable X means X < A in the sort
Group dependencies (gd), if we have an expression replacement with an antecedent with variables {A, B, C} and a replacement with variables {X, Y, Z}, one of {A, B, C} must be greater than all of {X, Y, Z}

If a group dependency antecedent only includes a variable (one of {A} must be greater than all of {X, Y, Z}), we turn it into the equivalent X < A, Y < A, Z < A
My current approach for the sort

First, I perform the sort treating group dependencies like normal dependencies (forcing all variables of the antecedent to depend on every variable of the replacement)
When I cannot procede, I check for any gd that have been solved. If so, they can be eliminated and I try to solve again.
If none of the gd have been solved, I search for a gd where one of the variables of the antecedent is only constrained by that gd1 (I will call it A). Making a copy of the sort thus far, I select one of the variables that is not A (I will call it B)2. I create normal dependencies where B depends on all the variables of the replacement and remove the gd.
If the sort fails, I try with another variable B
If all variables fail, I try to find another suitable gd
If no gd works, the sort fails

This is the approach I have found. I feel that it can spend a lot of time trying to find a solution in a path were a solution doesn't exist.
1 I believe that if all variables have other dependencies (even if only gd), no progress could be made
2 gd have more than one variable in the antecedent because if not they are turned into various normal dependencies
